# Code pass in if statement and else statement

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I try to past an `if… else` statement based on if a computer may be in the database. I made some research, find something good for me, but it’s seemed not perfect, since, it pas through my `if`…. And through my `else` in the same time…. My issue it’s I got my alert `Hello world`, not my `function (popup)` and it insert information into my database. Maybe I made a mistake in my code, and can’t find it.

What I want, if went the `$computername ==` a computer in database `($nomComputer as $info)`, the `insert into` didn’t work until a made yes in the `popup` somehow (It’s a little bit different because I need to do an `update` before the `insert into` and I want first adjust the `if else` statement).... but if the computer name it’s not in database, it will be insert into the database.

I also change the else by else `if($computername!=$info)` for this result : I pass the first `if($computername==$info)` without making anything when I put a computer name similar that one in the database and insert it directly.

I find nothing that helping me in all question that I pass by (all other that I see was in different language of PHP/jQuery (like python or C++)).

It’s there anything wrong in the code that make it past in the `if` statement and also the else statement?

This is my validation where a put my `foreach` contain the if statement

```
//Get informations in the form and insert it into db
    $location=$_GET['location'];
    $dept=$_GET['dept'];
    $jack=$_GET['jack'];
    $computername=$_GET['computername'];
    $productkey=$_GET['productkey'];
    $model=$_GET['model'];
    $vendor=$_GET['vendor'];
    $serialnumber=$_GET['serialnumber'];
    $macaddress=$_GET['macaddress'];
    $status=$_GET['status'];
    $starphone=$_GET['starphone'];
    $intid=$_GET['intid'];
    $did=$_GET['did'];
    $software=$_GET['software'];
    $yes=$_GET['yes'];

    foreach($nomComputer as $info){
        if($computername==$info){
            "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(‘Hello World’);
                ;(function($) {
                    $(function() {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
                            appendTo: 'form'
                            , zIndex: 2
                            , modalClose: false
                        });
                     });
                })(jQuery);
            </script> ";            
    }else{
        //Insert Into departement
        $query='insert into department(
        department,
        location_id)values(
        "'.$dept.'",
        "'.$location.'")';
        if(valid_query($query)){
        $message .= "Enregistrement a ete mis a jour! Informations has been saved for department!<br>";
        }else{
                $message .= "Enregistrement n a pas ete mis a jour! Informations has not been saved for department<br>";
        }
        //Insert Into computer
        $query='insert into computer(
        computer_name,
        product_key,
        model,
        serial_number,
        status_id,
        starphone,
        inst_id,
        did,
        macaddress,
        software_id,
        hidden
        )values(
        "'.$computername.'",
        "'.$productkey.'",
        "'.$model.'",
        "'.$serialnumber.'",
        "'.$status.'",
        "'.$starphone.'",
        "'.$intid.'",
        "'.$did.'",
        "'.$macaddress.'",
        "'.$software.'",
        0
        )';
        if(valid_query($query)){
        $message .= "Enregistrement a ete mis a jour! Informations has been saved!<br>";
        }else{
                $message .= "Enregistrement n a pas ete mis a jour! Informations has not been saved<br>";
        }
        $query="select dept_id from department where department='".$dept."' and location_id='".$location."'";
        $deptid=select_query($query);
        $query="select computer_id from computer where macaddress='".$macaddress."'";
        $computerid=select_query($query);
        //Insert Into jack
        $query='insert into jack(
        jack_number,
        dept_id,
        location_id,
        computer_id
        )values(
        "'.$jack.'",
        "'.$deptid.'",
        "'.$location.'",
        "'.$computerid.'")';
        if(valid_query($query)){
        $message .= "Enregistrement a ete mis a jour! Informations has been saved for jack!<br>";
        }else{
                $message .= "Enregistrement n a pas ete mis a jour! Informations has not been saved for jack<br>";
        }
        //Insert Into computer_vendor
        $query='insert into computer_vendor(
        computer_id,
        vendor_id
        )values(
        "'.$computerid.'",
        "'.$vendor.'")';
        if(valid_query($query)){
        $message .= "Enregistrement a ete mis a jour! Informations has been saved for vendor!<br>";
        }else{
                $message .= "Enregistrement n a pas ete mis a jour! Informations has not been saved for vendor<br>";
        }
        $location="";
        $dept="";
        $jack="";
        $computername="";
        $productkey="";
        $model="";
        $vendor="";
        $serialnumber="";
        $macaddress="";
        $status="";
        $starphone="";
        $intid="";
        $did="";

        $messageValide="Enregistrement a ete mis a jour! Informations has been saved";//Display went validate
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

This is my loop to get the computer name already in database

```
header( 'content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
require_once("cnx_db_inventory.php");
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
    //Get number of rows
    $sql="SELECT computer_name FROM computer";
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $i=1;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $nomComputer[$i] = $row['computer_name'];
        $i++;
    } 

// Loop through the results from the database
for ($i = 1; $i <=count($nomComputer); $i++){
        $nomComputer[$i];
}
```

The `popup` that I try to insert (right now, it’s on a button, but want it in the `if statement` (I try a bit))

```
;(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('#my-button').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
                appendTo: 'form'
                , zIndex: 2
                , modalClose: false
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And the `popup` content :

```
<!-- Button that triggers the popup -->
<button id="my-button">POP IT UP</button>
<!-- Element to pop up -->
<div id="element_to_pop_up">
    <h3>ATTENTION</h3>
    <p>This computer is already active in the database.</p>
    <p>Did you want to deactive the computer in the database and insert the new one?</p>
    <div align="right"><a id="yes" name="yes">Yes</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a class="b-close">No</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </div>
</div>
```

Exemple of computer name in the [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nwnm.png)

**EDIT**
Anyone got idea? I'm tried a lot of thing ( use `===` instead of `==`, put off the `alert`, put the `$function` in comments (the one in the if)) without success. My code still pass in the `if` statement AND the `else` statement! Maybe it is something else, but I can't put the finger on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem it was that I put my `if` and `else` statement in the `foreach`, so I made the `foreach` first and after the `if ... else`

```
    foreach($nomComputer as $info){
        if($computername==$info){
            $foundIt = $computername;
        }
    }
        if($computername==$foundIt){
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                ;(function($) {
                    $(function() {
                        $('#element_to_pop_up').bind('click', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
                                appendTo: 'form'
                                , zIndex: 2
                                , modalClose: false
                            });
                        });
                     });
                })(jQuery);
            </script> ";
        }else{
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `echo` to output the script. Right now you only have the string.

```
if($computername==$info){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(‘Hello World’);
            ;(function($) {
                $(function() {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
                        appendTo: 'form'
                        , zIndex: 2
                        , modalClose: false
                    });
                 });
            })(jQuery);
        </script> ";            
}else{
...
```

Comment: is it inserting a new record?

Comment: I don't understand. it's not possible for it to bypass both with a simple `else` statement. What exactly is happening? Did you check the html source code in the browser?

Comment: I resolve my problem of the both statement, I was to answer to my question to it. I have only a problem with my bPopup thosen show when it's in the if($computer==$info)

Comment: I resolve for my other problem with the popup. Thanks inarilo